# Bash Command Line Colors

Tags: bash

Bash provides the feature of colors for specific types of files. For example, by default ls will show directories as blue, utilities as green, files as white and etc. I know these colors can be customized for the output of commands such as ls via modifying ~/.dir_colors and other files depending upon how widespread on the system the change should be applied.

However, during screen-casts and presentations I have seen the **command line itself** have these color modifications. For example at the bash prompt if someone types a utility and starts typing its arguments, the utility on the line is colored green as it would be in the output of ls. This seems like a nice feature, but all google searches seem to turn up is how to modify outputs of ls and customize the colors, but not how to apply this to the command line itself. How can this be applied to the command line? Is it possible via bash or is this a feature of some terminal software these users are using?

Comment: Hm, dunno about bash, but [zsh has a lot of themes with that feature](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes)

Comment: [fish](http://fishshell.com/) does too

Comment: Thanks! It is definitely possible they were using another shell without me realizing it. I will look into these as an alternative in the case bash doesn't support it.

Comment: The first part is inaccurate... `ls` does the coors and the terminal showes it, bash is not involved... For similar output in tab completion, this might be useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-way-to-set-coloring-for-cd-tab-complete

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment too..
I think PS1 is what u r after.

Comment: I can only recommend other shells. While it might be possible to have basic prompt colors in Bash, the shell itself never really focused on such extras. I've been using Zsh for around ten years and I can only recommend it. The themes, autocompletion and other features make the command line usage very comfortable. More recent alternative would be the aforementioned Fish shell.

Answer (score 1):

fish - the Friendly interactive shell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell looks like it reacts as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

[BLE.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh) is a powerful pure bash addition that can colorize command line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful it will be but the tput command can help with changing the colours and formatting of the command line.

For example, to change the colour of the text in your terminal to red you can do.

```
tput setaf 1
```

This accepts numerical arguments between 1 and 7. This could then be added to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` in order to set the colours at the time of user login or when a new terminal session is started.

Along with changing colours tput has the ability to make the text bold, underlined and more.

For more usage check out these pages:

TDLP - http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

Hack40- http://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, I always do this for every Mac and Linux server I have. Not only can you tell it to provide useful info such as "user@server-name: working/directory", but it's just plain fun!

I like to have mine tell me which Git branch I'm working on, when I'm inside a Git repository!

You just have to add one change to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_rc`

Here is a website the will help you generate the complicated code: https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html

And just so you have an example, here is what I use on my personal Mac (without the Git branch detection):

```
PS1='\[\033[02;36m\][\u@MBP:\[\033[02;33m\]\w]\$\[\033[00m\] '
```

The above code will give you:

1. A teal color showing your user and a static hostname: "user@MBP". You can rename the hostname to anything you like.
2. Then, a yellow 'current working directory'
3. Lastly followed by a '$' symbol and resets the colors back to white

Specifying the colors for different parts gets tricky. I'd definitely recommend using the generator. But if you want to blaze your own trail, here is a list of all the codes for the bash colors: http://blog.bigdinosaur.org/easy-ps1-colors/

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking how to color the things you type, not the prompt.

Comment: My bad. You're right. Looks like I completely misunderstood the question. A sad panda :(

Comment: No harm done. It's a good answer, just not to this question. ;) If you delete it you can get the -2 points reversed.

Comment: I think I shall keep it as my badge of idiocy. Also, who knows, maybe someone will stumble on this article and find the info useful to them.

Answer (score 0):

To have it set every time you login to your workstation add above export command to your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file or `$HOME/.bashrc` file.

```sh
vi $HOME/.bashrc
```

Append the following lines:

```sh
export PS1="\[\e[31m\][\[\e[m\]\[\e[38;5;172m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[38;5;153m\]\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[38;5;214m\]\W\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\]]\[\e[m\]\\$ "
 
cat<<'EOF'
           _..._
         .'     '.
        /  _   _  \
        | (o)_(o) |
         \(     ) /
         //'._.'\ \
        //   .   \ \
       ||   .     \ \
       |\   :     / |
       \ `) '   (`  /_
     _)``".____,.'"` (_
     )     )'--'(     (
      '---`      `---`
EOF
```

Save and close the file in vim/vi.

To get into the ex mode, press [Esc] key and then : (the colon). For example, to exit from vi saving changes, press [Esc], : (colon) and type **wq**:

```sh
:wq
```

You can also quit, discard all changes by pressing [Esc], : (colon) and **q!**.

```sh
:q!
```

You need to press [Esc] key followed by the colon (:) before typing the following commands:

```sh
| Command       | Description                                                       |
|-------------  |----------------------------------------------------------------   |
| q             | Quit                                                              |
| q!            | Quit without saving changes i.e. discard changes and quit file    |
| r fileName    | Read data from file called fileName                               |
| w             | Save file and continue editing                                    |
| wq            | Write and quit (save and exit)                                    |
| x             | Same as wq command i.e. write and quit (save and exit)            |
| w fileName    | Write to file called fileName (save as)                           |
| w! fileName   | Overwrite to file called fileName (save as forcefully)            |
```